# Estimating the actual distance by using a series of measurements in between

Tags: spatial, distance, measurement

An object is moving along a single axis, back and forth. We take $N$ snapshots of the object. For all pairs of snapshot positions $i$ and $j$, we can make signed measurements of distance $x_{i,j} = -x_{j,i}$, but only once for each pair. Each of these measurements has some normally distributed error, and we can estimate its variance $\sigma^2_{i,j}$ for each measurement.

What would be the best estimate of the actual distance between points $1$ and $N$?

It's simple to just take $x_{1,N}$, but we obviously have more information than that. I was thinking of calculating all possible paths from $1$ to $N$, summing distances and variances along those paths, and then taking the best one. I believe I could write a program to do this in $O(n^2)$, but it doesn't feel like it combines all the information -- it just takes the 'shortest' path and ignores the rest.

As always, I have no idea which tags to use on this Stack Exchange so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You might find [Kalman filters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) useful

Comment: @user20160 That's a nice idea and a good link, but there's a twist here: if you conceive of the snapshots as a sequence of measurements over time, notice that as time goes on, more and more (presumably independent) measurements are made for each point, not just one new measurement. Also, there are no postulated physical dynamics for this object that a Kalman filter could exploit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z_i$ be the true positions for $i=1,2,\ldots,N.$ For each $i=1,2,\ldots, N-1$ define

$$\beta_i = z_{i+1}-z_i$$

to be the true signed distance.  In these terms, $x_{i,j}$ measures $\beta_i + \beta_{i+1} + \cdots + \beta_{j-1}$ with a precision of $1/\sigma^2_{i,j}.$  **This is a linear model and Weighted Least Squares is a good choice for estimating its parameters $\beta_i.$**

---

Specifically, the model matrix $X$ has one row for each distance measurement and $n-1$ columns for the $n-1$ betas, indexed by $1$ through $N-1.$. The row for the measurement of $x_{i,j}$ has ones in positions between $i$ and $j$ inclusive and otherwise has zeros. Putting the measurements $x_{i,j}$ into a vector $\mathbf{x}$ in parallel with the rows of $X,$ and putting the variances $\sigma_{i,j}^2$ into another such vector $\sigma,$ the model is

$$\mathbf{x} = X\beta + \epsilon \circ \sigma$$

where $\epsilon$ is a vector of independent random errors of mean zero and unit variance.  "$\circ$" denotes the component-by-component scaling of those vectors by the components of $\sigma.$

Software typically fits such a model using a function that accepts $X,$ $\mathbf{x},$ and $\sigma$ as its arguments.  The function outputs (at a minimum) the estimated values of $\beta,$ written $\hat\beta,$ and a covariance matrix $\hat V$ of those estimates (which is essential for obtaining standard errors).  In particular, the estimated distance between $z_1$ and $z_N$ is $\hat\beta_1+\cdots+\hat\beta_{N-1} = \mathbf{1}_{N-1}^\prime \hat\beta$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $N-1$-vector of ones, whence its estimation variance is

$$\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{1}_{N-1}^\prime \hat\beta) = \mathbf{1}_{N-1}^\prime \hat V \mathbf{1}_{N-1}$$

(which simply is the sum of all the entries of $\hat V$).  The square root of this number is the standard error of the distance estimate.

---

For example, I generated a random sequence of $N=200$ numbers on the interval $[0,1]$ and added independent Gaussian noise to each of their differences, using variances ranging from $0.0005$ to $0.055$ and averaging $0.01.$  (The associated standard deviations $\sigma_{i,j}$ were therefore, on average, one-third the distance moved between each snapshot: that's a pretty big measurement error.)

I used weighted least squares to fit the $N-1=199$ parameters $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_{199},$ with the following results for the signed distance from $z_1$ to $z_{200},$ which is estimated as $\hat\beta_1 + \cdots + \hat\beta_{N-1}$ (the hats represent the individual parameter estimates):

```
      Estimate         Actual Standard error              Z 
   0.491944302    0.502549159    0.008167935   -1.298352188
```

`Z` is the number of standard errors between the estimate and the true distance.  Notice that the standard error of the estimate is only about $1/120$ times the standard deviation of each individual measurement: this reflects the use of *all* $\binom{200}{2} = 19900$ measurements in the estimate.

For more details, check out this `R` code to simulate data, fit this model, run some diagnostics, and display the results.

```R
#
# Generate data in a data frame `df`.
#
n <- 200
sigma <- 0.1

set.seed(17)
z <- runif(n)
x <- outer(z, z, `-`)
j <- rep(seq_len(n), n)[lower.tri(x)]
i <- rep(seq_len(n), each=n)[lower.tri(x)]
x <- x[lower.tri(x)]
sigma2 <- rgamma(length(c(x)), 3, 3) * sigma^2
df <- data.frame(dz = x,
                 x = x + rnorm(length(sigma2), 0, sqrt(sigma2)),
                 sigma2 = sigma2,
                 i=i,
                 j=j)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# Create a model matrix.
#
n <- with(df, max(c(i,j)))
zero <- rep(0, n-1)
B <- t(apply(as.matrix(df[c("i", "j")]), 1, function(ij) {
  b <- zero
  b[min(ij):(max(ij)-1)] <- 1
  b
}))
colnames(B) <- paste0("beta.", seq_len(n-1))
X <- cbind(df["x"], B)
#
# Conducted weighted least squares.
#
w <- 1 / df$sigma2
fit <- lm(x ~ . - 1, X, weights=w)
summary(fit)
#
# Compare the estimates to the actual values.
#
beta.hat <- coefficients(fit)
dz <- diff(z)
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit)))
Z <- (beta.hat - dz) / se
Result <- data.frame(Fit = beta.hat,
                     Actual = dz,
                     `Standard Error` = se,
                     `Z score` = Z)
if (n <= 10) print(Result, digits=3)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
with(Result, {
  qqnorm(Z, main="Z scores")
  abline(0:1, col="Red", lwd=2)
  
  H <- hist(Z, plot=FALSE)
  plot(H, ylim=c(0, max(c(H$density, 1/sqrt(2*pi)))),
   freq=FALSE, main="Histogram of Z scores", col="#f0f0f0")
  curve(dnorm(z), xname="z", add=TRUE, lwd=2, col="Red")
})
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#
# Follow-on tests.
#
ks.test(Result$Z, pnorm) # Are the Z-scores Normal?
SE <- sqrt(rep(1,n-1) %*% vcov(fit) %*% rep(1,n-1))
c(Estimate = sum(beta.hat), Actual = z[n] - z[1], `Standard error` = SE, 
  Z = (sum(beta.hat) - (z[n] - z[1])) / SE)
```

Comment: Sounds like the prefect solution I wished for. Unfortunately, I'm not that fluent in statistics and, regrettably, I never took the time to learn R. It's a handicap. Am I right in my interpretation of your WLS setup? I started by stepping through the code and looking at the variables, but I gave up at B and tried to figure it out. Responses are `x_ij`s and parameters are betas. The model function is a dot product of those betas and the inputs, so it seems like inputs should just be flipping betas on or off and summing them. So inputs are vectors of i-1 zeros, then i-j ones and then 0s again?

Comment: That's right.  To help you out, I have added an English description of this setup.

Comment: That's great, thanks!